# How to loop through asynchrous calls sequentially?

Tags: angular, for-loop, asynchronous

I am using Angular2. The logic I want to implement is first to get the total page number, and then, I would like to loop through as many as obtained page number to get the items from server. However, it does not working as I expected because of asynchronous call.

Also, I have to get the ticket before calling an actual methods. At the final stage, whole items obtained from server also should be sorted and grouped. Following codes are what I've tried. I think this is not correct.

```
ngOnInit(): void {
        let page_count: number = 1;

        if(this.id) {
            this.searchService.getPageNum(this.id).subscribe((data: Object) => {
                page_count=(<Base>data).pageCount;
                console.log("page_count\t" + page_count);

                this.items = [];
                for(let i=1; i<=page_count; i++) {
                    this.searchService.getItems(this.id, i).subscribe((data: Object) => { this.generateItems(data) ; });
                }

                console.log("items num\t" + this.items.length);
                this.sortItems();
                this.groupItems();

            });
        }
    }

    getPageNum(id: string) {
    return this.userAuthService.getTicket()
    .switchMap((data:string) => {
      let url = this.config.baseUrl + cui + '/items?ticket=' + data;
      return this.http.get(url)
       .map( (responseData) => {return responseData.json()})
     });
    }

    getItems(id: string, pageNum: number) {
    return this.userAuthService.getTicket()
    .switchMap((data:string) => {
      let url = this.config.baseUrl + cui + '/items?ticket=' + data +'&pageNumber=' + pageNum;
      return this.http.get(url)
       .map( (responseData) => {return responseData.json()})
     });
    }
```

When I print the number of items, it does give me just '0'. I think I am still poor at asynchronous calls.

Comment: where in the code arw you pushing the items in this.items array?

Comment: I am not quite familier with AngularJS 2, but only with ES5/6 and since Angular's construction lays on Javascript I might help. As far as I can see you aren't pushing anything to `this.items`. Neither in nor outside the for-loop.

Comment: One more thing your for loop is synchronous and the getItems function is async you cant console.log right after the forloop you will always get 0 even if you are pushing items in this.items

Comment: aside from the fact that items are not pushed into the array, like say the previous comments, you have to take in account that you cannot predict when an asynchronous calls back. It means that the loop launches all the getItems functions, but the result is not arrived yet when you console.log and sort. This has to be treated in the function that is called in response, this is here that you must check if process is finished, and continue with sorting

Comment: Thank you, but I am pushing items into items array. It is done in the generateItems() method, I did not post in here though.

Comment: So, what could be a solution? :)

Comment: one solution is to check the length of array if i variable reached limit then print this.items. I an not quite familiar with angular2 but if you can use Promise.mapSeries function in Angular2 then you can gurantee the sequential execution plus you will exactly know when the loop is done

Answer (score 2):

```
let checkFlag = 1;
    for(let i=1; i<=page_count; i++) {
            this.searchService.getItems(this.id, i).subscribe((data: Object) => { 
                this.generateItems(data) ; 
                checkFlag++;
                if(page_count === checkFlag){
                    console.log("items num\t" + this.items.length); //if you are pushing items in this.generateItems function.
                }
            });
    }
```

i have used checkFlag because value of i will be max even if all the callbacks are not triggered yet so i am incrementing checkFlag whenever callback is triggered and when max results are fetched checkFlag value will be max and that time we will print this.items.

Comment: Is there any different way to implement this using asynchronous functions with callbacks? :)

Comment: I am not familiar with Angular2 much but there is library name async which provides methods to serially execute the loop and next iteration in loop only runs when first one is completed this functionaily is also provided in Es6 promises but i dont know if you can use this in Angular2. :)